# In golang, struct with a slice variable of any type is possible?

Tags: go

Simple golang app gives below error

```
.\test.go:13: cannot use ds (type Data_A) as type []interface {} in field value
```

for below code

```
package main

type Data_A struct {
    a string
}

type DTResponse struct {
    Data []interface{} `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    ds := Data_A{"1"}
    dtResp := &DTResponse{ Data:ds}

    print(dtResp)
}
```

I would like to have a struct with slice variable of any type. Using `struct{}` gives the same error.

In Java I could use Object as it is the parent object of any object. But I could not find such one in golang.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface. Duplicate.

Comment: Try this: https://play.golang.org/p/2MgthMr-8v

Comment: It helps me a lot. Thank you both of you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as a slice of `interface{}` which can hold any arbitrary value.

```
var s = []interface{}{1, 2, "three", SomeFunction}
fmt.Printf("Hello, %#v \n", s)
```

Output:

```
Hello, []interface {}{1, 2, "three", (func())(0xd4b60)}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/MQMc689StO

But I do not recommend simulate dynamic-typed languages (like Python, JavaScript, PHP, etc) this way. Better to use all static-typed benefits from Go, and leave this feature as a last resort, or as a container for user input. Just to receive it and convert to strict types.

Answer (score 0):

#### Typing

Go is a strongly explicitly typed language thus you can't substitute an object of one type with another (it is already compiled in this way). Also when you do `type Data_A struct {...` you define new type named `Data_A`. `[]interface{}` and `Data_A` are completely different types and these types (like any other) are not interchangeable. Note, even `interface{}` is not interchangeable with anything. You can pass any type in a function like this `func f(a interface{}){...` but inside the function you will have exactly `interface{}` type and you should assert it to use properly.

#### Fix#1

```
package main

type Data_A struct {
    a string
}

type DTResponse struct {
    Data Data_A `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    ds := Data_A{"1"}
    dtResp := &DTResponse{ Data:ds}

    print(dtResp)
}
```

#### Fix#2

```
package main

type DTResponse struct {
    Data []interface{} `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    ds := []interface{}{"1"}
    dtResp := &DTResponse{ Data:ds}

    print(dtResp)
}
```

Possibly the cause of confusion: struct is not slice or array.